# Django 1.1 beta 1 - Flatpages Error, Debug = False, with 404.html

Tags: django, django-flatpages

The Django flatpages application has a well-known and oft-discussed-on-the-web bug related to a missing *404.html* "Page Not Found" template in your project's templates directory. If you have DEBUG = False in your *settings.py* file, and you're missing the *404.html* file, flatpages will generate a 500 server error instead of loading the flatpage because the project tries to find the *404.html* template, and the 500 is generated because it isn't there.

My problem is different than this. I do have a *404.html* in my templates directory, hooked into my project, the middleware is hooked up, the SITE_ID is correct for each flatpage, and the *templates/flatpages/default.html* file exists.

When I try to load any flatpage, I get my custom *404.html* error page returned to me. So, the 404 template is working, but the flatpage middleware doesn't seem to be checking the URLs in the flatpage models, before it falls back on the 404.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or found a solution? This is a beta version, so perhaps a solution is in the works as I type. I'm using Django 1.1 beta 1.

Here is my entire MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'djangodblog.DBLogMiddleware',
    'ecomstore.SSLMiddleware.SSLRedirect',
    'ecomstore.marketing.urlcanon.URLCanonicalizationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Can you post your full MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting?

Answer (score 2):

I browsed the flatpage sources and solved the same problem by adding a slash to the end of the page URL in the admin area.

Comment: haha lol, true that. i wasted an hour right now solving this bug. i had to prepend also a slash. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. After a lot of chekcing I finally fixed it by turning on "Enable comments" (in the admin interface) for the flatpage in question...

On page http://www.petersanchez.com/2007/08/19/django-flatpages-wtf/ 
Peter Sanchez lists 4 checks to do, but it did not help in my case.

Comment: Hello Peter, I tried "Enable comments" for my three flatpages and it didn't fix the issue for me. I also came across that post before and it didn't help me either. Thanks for sharing.